# Characterize all sets of $2\times 2$ real matrices isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ as a field

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

> Let $A$ be the set of all 2x2 real matrices of  the form $$\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}$$ Show that a set $B$ of $2\times 2$ real matrices is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ as a field iff $B=gAg^{-1}$ for some invertible real matrix $g$.

---

I've shown that any field of the above form is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$, but I cannot figure out how to prove the other direction, that if $B$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ then it is of the above form. I can't find any way to characterize what $g$ would have to be for a given $B$. The statement is basically equivalent to saying the set $B$ is the set of all matrices representing the linear operators on the vector space $\mathbb C$ over $\mathbb R$ of the form $T_w(z)=wz$ under some basis, but I cannot prove that either.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try thinking of what matrices could correspond with $1$ and $i$.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2840152/81360) is related

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two caveats, and some high-level hints:

**First,** the claim you're asked to prove is not necessarily true! There exist proper subsets of $\mathbb C$ that are field-isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ itself, and such a set will map to a proper subset of $A$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ but certainly doesn't have the shape specified for $B$ in the problem.

(To *prove* that such a subset exists requires the axiom of choice, but it won't help us to decide to work in ZF -- if we prove the claim from ZF we would have *disproved* the axiom of choice, and a result of Gödel (no, not the famous one) states that the axiom of choice *cannot* be disproved in ZF -- unless ZF is inconsistent, in which case they sky is falling anyway).

In order to fix this and get something that *can* be proved, we need to revise the claim in one of two ways:

1. Replace "isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ as a field" with "isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ as an $\mathbb R$-algebra" -- that is, require that scaling a matrix in $B$ by a real constant corresponds, via the isomorphism, to multiplying the complex number by that *same* real number. Or,
2. Require that $B$ is a *closed* subset of $\mathbb R^{2\times 2}$.

**Second,** it is not really clear just what was meant by "isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ as a field" in the first place. For example, if $D$ is the set of $\mathbb 3\times 3$ matrices of the form
$$ \begin{bmatrix}a & -b & 0 \\ b & a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$
should we then consider $D$ to be "isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ as a field"? It definitely is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ as an $\mathbb R$-algebra, but $1\in\mathbb C$ is not represented by the identity element of $\mathbb R^{3\times 3}$. Now, the concept of a *field* homomorphism does require that $1$ maps to $1$, but $\mathbb R^{3\times 3}$ is *not* a field, and it is not *a priori* clear whether or not viewing a subset of it as a field should require us to use the particular identity element from the surrounding non-field.

**Back in the $2\times 2$ case:** We assume that an isomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb C\to B$ has been given. If we *can't* assume that $\varphi(1) = I_{2\times 2}$, then the solution will need some additional footwork to get started. In particular, then we don't automatically know that $\varphi(i)$ must be a solution of $X^2 = -I_{2\times 2}$. We can in fact still get through by instead starting with $X^3 = -X$ (together with $X\ne 0$), but there are additional details to keep track of in that case.

In each of these cases, some thinking about either $X^2 = -I$ or $X^3 = -X$ should enable you to find an invertible basis change $g$ such that
$$X = g\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}g^{-1}.$$
If you don't yet know that $\varphi(1) = I_{2\times 2}$, computing $-X^2$ in terms of $g$ will show it now.

If you have decided that $B$ must be an $\mathbb R$-algebra and isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ as such, it is now easy to conclude that $B$ is in fact identical to $gAg^{-1}$.

However, if all you know is that $B$ is *closed*, it's not quite that straightforward. Now that you know that $I\in B$, you can show that $\lambda I \in B$ for every real $\lambda$ -- but beware that this doesn't guarantee that $\lambda I=\varphi(\lambda)$! Since $B$ is closed under matrix multiplication and addition, we can then at least conclude $gAg^{-1} \subseteq B$. But an additional argument will be needed to show that $B$ cannot be *larger* than $gAg^{-1}$. One strategy could be to show that if there is a $b\in B$ with $g^{-1}bg\notin A$, then you can find an nonzero non-invertible element in $B$ -- which certainly cannot represent anything from $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the other answer, I agree that the way it's phrased right now is not quite correct.  I think we should rephrase such that $B$ is a unital $\mathbb R$-subalgebra of $M_2(\mathbb R)$ which is isomorphic as an $\mathbb R$ algebra to $\mathbb C$.  Of course $B$, being linearly isomorphic to $\mathbb C$, is a $2$-dimensional $\mathbb R$ vector space.

With that in mind, suppose $B$ is ($\mathbb R$-linearly) ring isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ and define $\tilde I=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $I$ be the identity matrix. Of course, $A$ and $B$ share the same identity $I$, which the isomorphism preserves.

Then $B$ contains an element $J$ whose characteristic (and minimal) polynomial is $X^2+1=0$. It is a [well-known exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/56725/29335) that matrices with side length $3$ or less over a field are similar if they have the same characteristic polynomial and minimal polynomial. Then since $J$ and $\tilde I$ have the same characteristic (and minimal) polynomial, there exists an invertible matrix $g$ such that $J=g\tilde Ig^{-1}$.

Since conjugation by $g$ is an injective $\mathbb R$-linear map, it's guaranteed to be *onto* $B$ (considering dimensions.) It is also a ring homomorphism, so indeed it is an $\mathbb R$-algebra isomorphism of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: "matrices with side length 3 or less over a field are similar if they have the same characteristic polynomial" -- wouldn't that make $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ similar?

Comment: @Troposphere You overlooked the part about "same minimal polynomial" . See the link.  looks like I typed it in two places but not in that one!