# *algebra embedding from complex matrices into real matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, c-star-algebras

I want algebra embeddings from $\text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{C})$ into $\text{Mat}_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ which preserve self-adjoitness and positive definiteness. So, this embedding should be involutive. Two natural embeddings are $A \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} A_R & A_I \\ -A_I& A_R\end{bmatrix}$ and $A \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} A_R & -A_I \\ A_I& A_R\end{bmatrix}$, where $A=A_R+iA_I$. So, all the *-embedding that I know has the form $A \mapsto O^T \begin{bmatrix} A_R & A_I \\ -A_I& A_R\end{bmatrix}O$ where $O$ is an orthogonal matrix. Is there any other *-embedding? If not how can we show that?

Comment: I suspect that you can show that every convolutive algebra embedding arises from an embedding of $\Bbb C^n$ into $\Bbb R^{n}$. Note that your second natural embedding arises from the map $\phi: x + iy \mapsto \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} x\\y \end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Comment: I think it is useful. So M2n(R) is a central simple algebra of dimension 2n over reals, and Mn(C) is R-algebra. Hence, all the embeddings are related by conjugation. Now, if we want these embeddings to be involutive then all of them are related to each other by orthogonal conjugation. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer is incomplete; I'm just posting it to ensure it stays saved on the site and in case it is useful in its incomplete form*

---

We aim to show that for any convolutive algebraic embedding $\Phi:\mathcal M_n(\Bbb C) \to \mathcal M_{2n}(\Bbb R)$, there is an associated orthogonal matrix $O$.

To that end, begin by considering the element $J = \Phi(i\,\text{id}_{\Bbb C^n})$. Because $\Phi$ is adjoint-preserving, the fact that $[i\,\text{id}_{\Bbb C^n}]^* = -i\,\text{id}_{\Bbb C^n}$ implies that
$$
J^* = 
\Phi([i\,\text{id}_{\Bbb C^n}]^*) = \Phi(-[i\,\text{id}_{\Bbb C^n}]) = - \Phi(i\,\text{id}_{\Bbb C^n}) = -J.
$$
Because $J$ is skew self-adjoint with $J^2 = -\text{id}_{\Bbb R^{2n}}$, we can conclude that there exists an orthogonal matrix $O_1$ such that
$$
J = O_1\pmatrix{0 & -I\\ I & 0}O_1^T.
$$
Indeed, the spectral theorem ensures that the matrices $J$ and $\left[ \begin{smallmatrix}0&-I\\I&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ are unitarily similar (since they are unitarily diagonalizable with the same eigenvalues), and it generally holds that two unitarily similar real matrices are necessarily orthogonally similar.

Conclude from the fact that $\Phi(A)$ commutes with $J$ (for all $A \in \mathcal M_n(\Bbb C)$) that we must have the form
$$
\Phi(A) = O_1\pmatrix{f(A) & -g(A)\\ g(A) & f(A)}O_1^T
$$
for some maps $f,g:\mathcal M_n(\Bbb C) \to \mathcal M_n(\Bbb R)$.

Now, note that for any $A \in \mathcal M_n(\Bbb R)$,
$$
O_1\pmatrix{f(iA) & -g(iA)\\
g(iA) & f(iA)}O_1^T = \\
\Phi(iA)  = J\Phi(A) = \\
O_1\pmatrix{-g(A) & -f(A)\\
f(A) & -g(A)}O_1^T.
$$
So, we have
$$
f(iA) = - g(A)\\
g(iA) = f(A).
$$

---

A relevant note:

Your "natural" algebra embeddings arise from an embedding of the underlying spaces. In particular, consider the map $\phi_0:\Bbb C^n \to \Bbb R^{2n}$ given by $\phi_0(x + iy) = \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} x\\y \end{smallmatrix}\right]$. To compute the adjoint of $\phi_0$ relative to the usual inner product on $\Bbb R^{2n}$ and the real inner product $\langle w,z\rangle = \operatorname{Re}[w^*z]$ over $\Bbb C^n$, note that if we define $\psi:\left[ \begin{smallmatrix} x\\y \end{smallmatrix}\right] \mapsto x + iy$, then
$$
\begin{align*}
\left\langle \phi_0(x + iy), \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle
&= 
\left\langle \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle = x^Ta + y^Tb\\
\left\langle x + iy, \psi\left(\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}\right)\right\rangle 
&= 
\langle x + iy, a + ib \rangle = x^Ta + y^Tb,
\end{align*}
$$
So, that $\psi = \phi_0^*$. With that, we have
$$
\pmatrix{A_R & -A_I\\A_I & A_R} \pmatrix{x\\y} = (\phi_0 \circ A \circ \phi_0^*) (x + iy).
$$
Note that for any orthogonal matrix $O$, $\phi = O^T \circ \phi_0$ induces the embedding
$$
O^T\pmatrix{A_R & -A_I\\A_I & A_R}O
$$
in the same way.

Comment: Great, thank you. Just some questions: do you mean $J$ is skew self adjoint and $J^2 = -id$?  How do you conclude that there exists orthogonal $O_1$ which gives rise to such a decomposition of $J$?

Comment: @khashayar I've edited my post to address your comment in more detail

Comment: @khashayar Regarding $J$ see also the [spectral properties of skew-symmetric matrices on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Spectral_theory)

Comment: @khashayar That was an unfortunate mistake, I'm glad you figured it out